# Can't change height of table cell

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically change the height of a cell than contains a div.  Now i can change the height of the div, just fine, but when I try the cell, it just doesn't work, yet I get no errors.  Any Ideas on why this doesn't work?

```
if( df0.checkbox1.checked)
{
    document.getElementById('layerOne').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('layerOne').style.height = 125;
    document.getElementById('eftcell').height = '125px'
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('layerOne').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('layerOne').style.height = 1; 
    document.getElementById('eftcell').height = '1px'
}
```

Comment: It's "height".. and that indentation style is horrid!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say, I am using "height"

Comment: Not originally in the text and title.

Comment: but my code was good though (at least in the spelling of height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of testing in FireFox 4 (via Firebug), it seems to work for me. Here are some things to look for:

- Try using just the number `125` for height, rather than the string `'125px'`
- Make sure that the element with `id="eftcell"` is the `<td>` element, not its parent `<tr>`
- Look into compatibility issues between browsers, maybe your browser doesn't allow a `height` attribute on `<td>`?

Comment: I do have the ID set on the cell, not the row, and I have tried both 125 and '125px', neither seems to have an effect.

Comment: Could it be that table cell has additional CSS style applied to it? Inline style rules will override the `height` attribute on the `<td>` element.

Comment: Think I found the problem.  I am resetting the DIV size, but its not shrinking smaller than the elements inside it.  I know I can take its size to nothing, but as i remember, there is one more setting i need to change.

Comment: Ok, i found it.  I had to set the overflow attribute to hidden for the div as well.  Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 3):

Use the "px" unit when changing `style.property`:

```
document.getElementById('layerOne').style.height = "125px";
document.getElementById('eftcell').height = 125;
```

Comment: Yeah, to be correct i should of had the px and the style, but they weren't throwing errors right away, so i thought i would worry about that later  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Needs px and to be in a string. Also HTML5 doesn't support javascript height on TD cells.